# Files in Lua program not able to reference each other's variables

Tags: oop, lua, global-variables, cs50, love2d

I'm hoping somebody experienced can point out where/if I am missing some crucial syntax.
My program works fine (because 95% of it was created by a CS50 professor), with one exception - I cannot seem to get the player and flag files/classes to reference each other to show that my Mario character has reached the final flag.
Specifically, the function "Flag:victory(player)" does not appear to be pulling information from the player file/class, while player has a similar function that is able to access Flag, although I don't see any difference between the two files as to why Flag is not behaving properly.

```
Flag = Class{}


function Flag:init(map)
    -- reference to map for checking tiles
   
    self.texture = map.spritesheet
    
    -- animation frames
    self.frames = {}

    -- current animation frame
    self.currentFrame = nil
    self.player = Player(map)

    -- used to determine behavior and animations
    self.state = 'waving'

    -- x and y velocity
    self.dy = 0

    -- position on top of map tiles
    self.y = map.tileHeight * ((map.mapHeight / 2) - 4) 
    self.x = (map.mapWidth - 3) * map.tileWidth

    -- initialize all player animations
    self.animations = {
        ['waving'] = Animation({
            texture = self.texture,
            frames = {
                love.graphics.newQuad(0, 48, 16, 16, self.texture:getDimensions()),
                love.graphics.newQuad(16, 48, 16, 16, self.texture:getDimensions()),
                love.graphics.newQuad(0, 48, 16, 16, self.texture:getDimensions()),
            },
            interval = 0.30
        }),
        ['falling'] = Animation({
            texture = self.texture,
            frames = {
                love.graphics.newQuad(32, 48, 16, 16, self.texture:getDimensions())
            }
        })
    }

    -- initialize animation and current frame we should render
    self.animation = self.animations['waving']
    self.currentFrame = self.animation:getCurrentFrame()
end

function Flag:update(dt)
    self.animation:update(dt)
    self.currentFrame = self.animation:getCurrentFrame()
    self:victory()
end
 
function Flag:render()
    local scaleX = - 1

    -- draw sprite with scale factor and offsets
    love.graphics.draw(self.texture, self.currentFrame, math.floor(self.x + 8 / 2),
        math.floor(self.y + 8 / 2), 0, scaleX, 1, 8 / 2, 8 / 2)
end

function Flag:victory(player)
    if self.player.victory == true then -- when player reaches flag
        self.state = 'falling' -- change flag animation to down sprite
        self.animation = self.animations['falling']
        self.y = self.y + 2 -- descend the flag
    end 
end
```

```
--[[
    Represents our player in the game, with its own sprite.
]]

Player = Class{}

local WALKING_SPEED = 140
local JUMP_VELOCITY = 400

function Player:init(map)
    
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.width = 16
    self.height = 20

    -- offset from top left to center to support sprite flipping
    self.xOffset = 8
    self.yOffset = 10

    -- reference to map for checking tiles
    self.map = map -- just a convenience because map comes in as a param/arg so the self should be dropped
    self.texture = love.graphics.newImage('graphics/blue_alien.png')

    -- sound effects
    self.sounds = {
        ['jump'] = love.audio.newSource('sounds/jump.wav', 'static'),
        ['hit'] = love.audio.newSource('sounds/hit.wav', 'static'),
        ['coin'] = love.audio.newSource('sounds/coin.wav', 'static'),
    }
    
    -- variable for playing sound just once when game ends
    self.musicplayed = false
    -- animation frames
    self.frames = {}

    -- current animation frame
    self.currentFrame = nil

    -- used to determine behavior and animations
    self.state = 'idle'

    -- determines sprite flipping
    self.direction = 'left'

    -- x and y velocity
    self.dx = 0
    self.dy = 0

    -- position on top of map tiles
    self.y = map.tileHeight * ((map.mapHeight - 2) / 2) - self.height
    self.x = map.tileWidth * 10
    self.xmax = self.x -- farthest that mario has ever gone to the right
    self.xmin = 1 -- farthest mario may go to the left, based on xmax and left border of map

    -- initialize all player animations
    self.animations = {
        ['idle'] = Animation({
            texture = self.texture,
            frames = {
                love.graphics.newQuad(0, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions())
            }
        }),
        ['walking'] = Animation({
            texture = self.texture,
            frames = {
                love.graphics.newQuad(128, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions()),
                love.graphics.newQuad(144, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions()),
                love.graphics.newQuad(160, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions()),
                love.graphics.newQuad(144, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions()),
            },
            interval = 0.15
        }),
        ['jumping'] = Animation({
            texture = self.texture,
            frames = {
                love.graphics.newQuad(32, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions())
            }
        }),
        ['victory'] = Animation({ 
            texture = self.texture,
            frames = {
                love.graphics.newQuad(0, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions()),
                love.graphics.newQuad(48, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions()),
                love.graphics.newQuad(0, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions()),
                love.graphics.newQuad(160, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions()),
                love.graphics.newQuad(0, 0, 16, 20, self.texture:getDimensions()),
            },
            interval = .25
        })
    }

    -- initialize animation and current frame we should render
    self.animation = self.animations['idle']
    self.currentFrame = self.animation:getCurrentFrame()

    -- behavior map we can call based on player state
    self.behaviors = {
        ['idle'] = function(dt)
        
            -- add spacebar functionality to trigger jump state
            if love.keyboard.wasPressed('space') then
                self.dy = -JUMP_VELOCITY
                self.state = 'jumping'
                self.animation = self.animations['jumping']
                self.sounds['jump']:play()
            elseif love.keyboard.isDown('left') then
                self.direction = 'left'
                self.dx = -WALKING_SPEED
                self.state = 'walking'
                self.animations['walking']:restart()
                self.animation = self.animations['walking']
                self:checkLeftBoundary()
            elseif love.keyboard.isDown('right') then
                self.direction = 'right'
                self.dx = WALKING_SPEED
                self.state = 'walking'
                self.animations['walking']:restart()
                self.animation = self.animations['walking']
            else
                self.dx = 0
            end

            self:checkLeftBoundary()
            self:checkRightBoundary()

        end,
        ['walking'] = function(dt)
            
            -- keep track of input to switch movement while walking, or reset
            -- to idle if we're not moving
            if love.keyboard.wasPressed('space') then
                self.dy = -JUMP_VELOCITY
                self.state = 'jumping'
                self.animation = self.animations['jumping']
                self.sounds['jump']:play()
            elseif love.keyboard.isDown('left') then
                self.direction = 'left'
                self.dx = -WALKING_SPEED
            elseif love.keyboard.isDown('right') then
                self.direction = 'right'
                self.dx = WALKING_SPEED
            else
                self.dx = 0
                self.state = 'idle'
                self.animation = self.animations['idle']
            end

            self:checkLeftBoundary()
            self:checkRightBoundary()

            -- check for collisions moving left and right
            self:checkRightCollision()
            self:checkLeftCollision()

            -- check if there's a tile directly beneath us
            if not self.map:collides(self.map:tileAt(self.x, self.y + self.height)) and
                not self.map:collides(self.map:tileAt(self.x + self.width - 1, self.y + self.height)) then
                
                -- if so, reset velocity and position and change state
                self.state = 'jumping'
                self.animation = self.animations['jumping']
        
            end
        end,
        ['jumping'] = function(dt)
            if love.keyboard.isDown('left') then
                self.direction = 'left'
                self.dx = -WALKING_SPEED
            elseif love.keyboard.isDown('right') then
                self.direction = 'right'
                self.dx = WALKING_SPEED
            end

            -- apply map's gravity before y velocity
            self.dy = self.dy + self.map.gravity

            -- check if there's a tile directly beneath us
            if self.map:collides(self.map:tileAt(self.x, self.y + self.height)) or
                self.map:collides(self.map:tileAt(self.x + self.width - 1, self.y + self.height)) then
                
                -- if so, reset velocity and position and change state
                self.dy = 0
                self.state = 'idle'
                self.animation = self.animations['idle']
                self.y = (self.map:tileAt(self.x, self.y + self.height).y - 1) * self.map.tileHeight - self.height
            end

            self:checkLeftBoundary()
            self:checkRightBoundary()

            -- check for collisions moving left and right
            self:checkRightCollision()
            self:checkLeftCollision()
        end,
        ['victory'] = function(dt)
            self.dx = 0
            -- check if there's a tile directly beneath us
            if self.map:collides(self.map:tileAt(self.x, self.y + self.height)) or
                self.map:collides(self.map:tileAt(self.x + self.width - 1, self.y + self.height)) then
                
                -- if so, reset velocity and position and change state
                self.dy = 0
                self.y = (self.map:tileAt(self.x, self.y + self.height).y - 1) * self.map.tileHeight - self.height
            end
        end
    }
end

function Player:update(dt)
    self.behaviors[self.state](dt)
    self.animation:update(dt)
    self.currentFrame = self.animation:getCurrentFrame()
    self.x = self.x + self.dx * dt
    self.xmax = math.max(self.x, self.xmax) -- tester to update xmax if player moves further to right than ever before
    self.xmin = math.max(1, math.min(self.xmax - VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2, map.mapWidthPixels - VIRTUAL_WIDTH))  -- farthest mario may go to the left, based on xmax and left border of map
    self:calculateJumps()

    self:gameover()
    self:reachflag()
    if self.map:victory() == true then
        self.victory = true
    end

    -- apply velocity
    self.y = self.y + self.dy * dt
end
 
function Player:gameover()
    if self.y > 300 then
        self.game_over = true 
    end
end 

function Player:reachflag(Flag)
    if self.x >= flag.x then
        self.victory = true
    end
end 

-- jumping and block hitting logic
function Player:calculateJumps()
    
    -- if we have negative y velocity (jumping), check if we collide
    -- with any blocks above us
    if self.dy < 0 then
        if self.map:tileAt(self.x, self.y).id ~= TILE_EMPTY or
            self.map:tileAt(self.x + self.width - 1, self.y).id ~= TILE_EMPTY then
            -- reset y velocity
            self.dy = 0

            -- change block to different block
            local playCoin = false
            local playHit = false
            if self.map:tileAt(self.x, self.y).id == JUMP_BLOCK then
                self.map:setTile(math.floor(self.x / self.map.tileWidth) + 1,
                    math.floor(self.y / self.map.tileHeight) + 1, JUMP_BLOCK_HIT)
                playCoin = true
            else
                playHit = true
            end
            if self.map:tileAt(self.x + self.width - 1, self.y).id == JUMP_BLOCK then
                self.map:setTile(math.floor((self.x + self.width - 1) / self.map.tileWidth) + 1,
                    math.floor(self.y / self.map.tileHeight) + 1, JUMP_BLOCK_HIT)
                playCoin = true
            else
                playHit = true
            end

            if playCoin then
                self.sounds['coin']:play()
            elseif playHit then
                self.sounds['hit']:play()
            end
        end
    end
end

-- checks two tiles to our left to see if a collision occurred
function Player:checkLeftCollision()
    if self.dx < 0 then
        -- check if there's a tile directly beneath us
        if self.map:collides(self.map:tileAt(self.x - 1, self.y)) or
            self.map:collides(self.map:tileAt(self.x - 1, self.y + self.height - 1)) then
            
            -- if so, reset velocity and position and change state
            self.dx = 0
            self.x = self.map:tileAt(self.x - 1, self.y).x * self.map.tileWidth
        end
    end
end

-- checks two tiles to our right to see if a collision occurred
function Player:checkRightCollision()
    if self.dx > 0 then
        -- check if there's a tile directly beneath us
        if self.map:collides(map:tileAt(self.x + self.width, self.y)) or
            self.map:collides(map:tileAt(self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height - 1)) then
            
            -- if so, reset velocity and position and change state
            self.dx = 0
            self.x = (self.map:tileAt(self.x + self.width, self.y).x - 1) * map.tileWidth - self.width
        end
    end
end

function Player:checkLeftBoundary()
    if self.x <= self.xmin then -- went too far left
        self.x = self.xmin
        if self.direction == 'left'then 
            self.dx = 0 -- set speed to zero but keep state, ie walking, jumping/falling
        end 
    end
end  

function Player:checkRightBoundary()
    if self.x >= map.mapWidthPixels - 16 then -- went too far right
        self.x = map.mapWidthPixels - 16 
        if self.direction == 'right'then 
            self.dx = 0 -- set speed to zero but keep state, ie walking, jumping/falling
        end 
    end
end  

function Player:render()
    local scaleX

    -- set negative x scale factor if facing left, which will flip the sprite
    -- when applied
    if self.direction == 'right' then
        scaleX = 1
    else
        scaleX = -1
    end

    -- draw sprite with scale factor and offsets
    love.graphics.draw(self.texture, self.currentFrame, math.floor(self.x + self.xOffset),
        math.floor(self.y + self.yOffset), 0, scaleX, 1, self.xOffset, self.yOffset)

    if self.game_over == true then
        self.state = 'idle'
        self.dy = 0
        self.dx = 0
        map.music:stop()
        if self.musicplayed == false then 
            love.audio.newSource('sounds/Laser_Shoot2.wav', 'static'):play()
            self.musicplayed = true
        end 
        love.graphics.print('Oh Snap!  Try again? (y/n)', self.xmin + 40, 40)
        if love.keyboard.isDown('y') then
            self.map:init()
            self.map:render()
        elseif love.keyboard.isDown('n')then
            love.event.quit()
        end  
    end 

    if self.victory == true then 
        self.state = 'victory'
        self.animation = self.animations['victory']
        if self.musicplayed == false then    
            love.audio.newSource('sounds/Powerup23.wav', 'static'):play()
            self.musicplayed = true
        end
        love.graphics.print('Congratulations! Play again? (y/n)', self.xmin + 35, 40)
        if love.keyboard.isDown('y') then
            self.map:init()
            self.map:render()
            map.music:stop()
        elseif love.keyboard.isDown('n')then
            love.event.quit()
        end   
    end
end
```

```
--[[
    Super Mario Bros. Demo
    Author: Colton Ogden
    Original Credit: Nintendo

    Demonstrates rendering a screen of tiles.
]]

Class = require 'class'
push = require 'push'

require 'Animation'
require 'Map'
require 'Player'
require 'Flag'
 
-- close resolution to NES but 16:9
VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 432
VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 243

-- actual window resolution
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720

-- seed RNG
math.randomseed(os.time())

-- makes upscaling look pixel-y instead of blurry
love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest', 'nearest')

-- an object to contain our map data
map = Map()
flag = Flag(map)
player = Player(map)

-- performs initialization of all objects and data needed by program
function love.load()

    -- sets up a different, better-looking retro font as our default
    love.graphics.setFont(love.graphics.newFont('fonts/font.ttf', 16))

    -- sets up virtual screen resolution for an authentic retro feel
    push:setupScreen(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, {
        fullscreen = false,
        resizable = true
    })

    love.window.setTitle('Super Mario 50')

    

    love.keyboard.keysPressed = {}
    love.keyboard.keysReleased = {}

end

-- called whenever window is resized
function love.resize(w, h)
    push:resize(w, h)
end

-- global key pressed function
function love.keyboard.wasPressed(key)
    if (love.keyboard.keysPressed[key]) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

-- global key released function
function love.keyboard.wasReleased(key)
    if (love.keyboard.keysReleased[key]) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

-- called whenever a key is pressed 
function love.keypressed(key)
    if key == 'escape' then
        love.event.quit()
    end

    love.keyboard.keysPressed[key] = true
end

-- called whenever a key is released
function love.keyreleased(key)
    love.keyboard.keysReleased[key] = true
end

-- called every frame, with dt passed in as delta in time since last frame
function love.update(dt)
    map:update(dt)
    
    
    -- reset all keys pressed and released this frame
    love.keyboard.keysPressed = {}
    love.keyboard.keysReleased = {}
end

-- called each frame, used to render to the screen
function love.draw()
    -- begin virtual resolution drawing
    push:apply('start')

    -- clear screen using Mario background blue
    love.graphics.clear(108/255, 140/255, 255/255, 255/255)

    -- renders our map object onto the screen
    love.graphics.translate(math.floor(-map.camX + 0.5), math.floor(-map.camY + 0.5))
    map:render()
    
    

    -- end virtual resolution
    push:apply('end')
end
```

```
--[[
    Contains tile data and necessary code for rendering a tile map to the
    screen.
]]

require 'Util'

Map = Class{}

TILE_BRICK = 1
TILE_EMPTY = -1

-- cloud tiles
CLOUD_LEFT = 6
CLOUD_RIGHT = 7

-- bush tiles
BUSH_LEFT = 2
BUSH_RIGHT = 3

-- mushroom tiles
MUSHROOM_TOP = 10
MUSHROOM_BOTTOM = 11

-- jump block
JUMP_BLOCK = 5
JUMP_BLOCK_HIT = 9

-- flagpole
FLAGPOLE_TOP = 8
FLAGPOLE_MIDDLE = 12
FLAGPOLE_BOTTOM = 16
PYRAMID_BLOCK = 17


-- a speed to multiply delta time to scroll map; smooth value
local SCROLL_SPEED = 62

-- constructor for our map object
function Map:init()
    self.spritesheet = love.graphics.newImage('graphics/spritesheet.png')
    self.sprites = generateQuads(self.spritesheet, 16, 16)
    self.music = love.audio.newSource('sounds/music.wav', 'static')
    self.pyramid_block = love.graphics.newImage('graphics/pyramidblock.png')

    self.tileWidth = 16
    self.tileHeight = 16
    self.mapWidth = 300
    self.mapHeight = 28
    self.tiles = {}

    -- applies positive Y influence on anything affected
    self.gravity = 15

    -- associate player with map
    self.player = Player(self)
    self.flag = Flag(self)

    -- camera offsets
    self.camX = 0
    self.camY = -3

    -- cache width and height of map in pixels
    self.mapWidthPixels = self.mapWidth * self.tileWidth
    self.mapHeightPixels = self.mapHeight * self.tileHeight

    -- first, fill map with empty tiles
    for y = 1, self.mapHeight do
        for x = 1, self.mapWidth do
            
            -- support for multiple sheets per tile; storing tiles as tables 
            self:setTile(x, y, TILE_EMPTY)
        end
    end

    -- begin generating the terrain using vertical scan lines
    local x = 1
    while x < self.mapWidth - 20 do
        
        -- 2% chance to generate a cloud
        -- make sure we're 2 tiles from edge at least
        if x < self.mapWidth - 2 then
            if math.random(20) == 1 then
                
                -- choose a random vertical spot above where blocks/pipes generate
                local cloudStart = math.random(self.mapHeight / 2 - 6)

                self:setTile(x, cloudStart, CLOUD_LEFT)
                self:setTile(x + 1, cloudStart, CLOUD_RIGHT)
            end
        end

        -- 5% chance to generate a mushroom
        if math.random(20) == 1 then
            -- left side of pipe
            self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - 2, MUSHROOM_TOP)
            self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - 1, MUSHROOM_BOTTOM)

            -- creates column of tiles going to bottom of map
            for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
            end

            -- next vertical scan line
            x = x + 1

        -- 10% chance to generate a bush, being sure to generate away from edge
        elseif math.random(10) == 1 and x < self.mapWidth - 3 then
            local bushLevel = self.mapHeight / 2 - 1

            -- place bush component and then column of bricks
            self:setTile(x, bushLevel, BUSH_LEFT)
            for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
            end
            x = x + 1

            self:setTile(x, bushLevel, BUSH_RIGHT)
            for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
            end
            x = x + 1

        -- 10% chance to not generate anything, creating a gap
        elseif math.random(10) ~= 1 then
            
            -- creates column of tiles going to bottom of map
            for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
            end

            -- chance to create a block for Mario to hit
            if math.random(15) == 1 then
                self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - 4, JUMP_BLOCK)
            end

            -- next vertical scan line
            x = x + 1
        else
            -- increment X so we skip two scanlines, creating a 2-tile gap
            x = x + 2
        end
    end

    while x <= self.mapWidth do
        
        -- draw in pyramid
        if x == self.mapWidth - 13 then
            local row = 1 -- how wide pyramid to be
            while row < 7 do
                local column = 1 -- might need to not say local everytime
                while column <= row do
                    self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - column, PYRAMID_BLOCK)
                    column = column + 1
                end
                 -- creates column of tiles going to bottom of map
                for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
                    self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
                end
                row = row + 1
                x = x + 1
            end
        end 
        
        -- draw in flagpole
        if x == self.mapWidth - 2 then
            self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - 3, FLAGPOLE_TOP)
            self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - 2, FLAGPOLE_MIDDLE)
            self:setTile(x, self.mapHeight / 2 - 1, FLAGPOLE_BOTTOM)
        end

        -- creates column of tiles going to bottom of map
        for y = self.mapHeight / 2, self.mapHeight do
            self:setTile(x, y, TILE_BRICK)
        end

        -- next vertical scan line
        x = x + 1    
    end     

    -- start the background music
    self.music:setLooping(true)
    self.music:play()
end

-- return whether a given tile is collidable
function Map:collides(tile)
    -- define our collidable tiles
    local collidables = {
        TILE_BRICK, JUMP_BLOCK, JUMP_BLOCK_HIT,
        MUSHROOM_TOP, MUSHROOM_BOTTOM, PYRAMID_BLOCK
    }

    -- iterate and return true if our tile type matches
    for _, v in ipairs(collidables) do
        if tile.id == v then
            return true
        end
    end

    return false
end

-- this function doesn't appear to be doing anything...
function Map:victory(player, flag)
    if self.player.x >= self.flag.x * map.tileWidth then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end


-- function to update camera offset with delta time
function Map:update(dt)
    self.player:update(dt)
    self.flag:update(dt)
    -- keep camera's X coordinate following the player, preventing camera from
    -- scrolling past 0 to the left and the map's width
    self.camX =  math.min(self.mapWidthPixels - VIRTUAL_WIDTH, math.max(self.camX, math.min(self.player.x - VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2,
        math.min(self.mapWidthPixels - VIRTUAL_WIDTH, self.player.x))))
end

-- gets the tile type at a given pixel coordinate
function Map:tileAt(x, y)
    return {
        x = math.floor(x / self.tileWidth) + 1,
        y = math.floor(y / self.tileHeight) + 1,
        id = self:getTile(math.floor(x / self.tileWidth) + 1, math.floor(y / self.tileHeight) + 1)
    }
end

-- returns an integer value for the tile at a given x-y coordinate
function Map:getTile(x, y)
    return self.tiles[(y - 1) * self.mapWidth + x]
end

-- sets a tile at a given x-y coordinate to an integer value
function Map:setTile(x, y, id)
    self.tiles[(y - 1) * self.mapWidth + x] = id
end

-- renders our map to the screen, to be called by main's render
function Map:render()
    for y = 1, self.mapHeight do
        for x = 1, self.mapWidth do
            local tile = self:getTile(x, y)
            if tile ~= TILE_EMPTY then
                if tile > 16 then
                    love.graphics.draw(self.pyramid_block,
                        (x - 1) * self.tileWidth, (y - 1) * self.tileHeight)
                else     
                    love.graphics.draw(self.spritesheet, self.sprites[tile],
                        (x - 1) * self.tileWidth, (y - 1) * self.tileHeight)
                end
            end
        end
    end
    self.player:render()   
    self.flag:render() 
end
```

Comment: I actually don't see you calling Flag:victory() anywhere?

Comment: Sorry about that!  I must have taken it out to try calling victory from map.  The function call is back in the code now.  Still not working though...

Comment: Could you add your main.lua?

Comment: I just added main.lua and map.lua.  Hopefully you can spot what is wrong.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using 'self.player' which is a brand new player at the init() (which is a different player than the one you want)
You need to use 'player' that you passed as an argument to check if player.victory is true.